# UIWebView's scrolling after textfield focus

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiwebview

I have `UIView` and `UIWebView` on screen. When I click on text field in website, web view content is going up. How could I force `UIView` to move as well then?

Answer (score 7):

You can subscribe to either the `UIKeyboardWillShowNotification` or the `UIKeyboardDidShowNotification`, and move your `UIView` when you receive the notification.  This process is described here:

[*Text, Web, and Editing Programming Guide for iOS*: “Moving Content That Is Located Under the Keyboard”](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/DOCUMENTATION/StringsTextFonts/Conceptual/TextAndWebiPhoneOS/KeyboardManagement/KeyboardManagement.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009542-CH5-SW7)

Comment: His answer is simpler than mine. Just register a callback for one of the notifications above within your view and you're done.

Comment: Well, you can jump from one text field to another so it requires some play with UIWebView's UIScrollView, not only these notifications, but that's really helpful. Thanks - bounty is yours.

Answer (score 5):

Maybe this helps: I didn't want the UIWebView to scroll at all, including when focusing on a textfield.

You have to be the delegate of the UIWebView:

```
_webView.scrollView.delegate = self;
```

And then add this method

```
- (void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView
{
    scrollView.contentOffset = CGPointZero;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

UIWebView has a callback:

```
- (BOOL)webView:(UIWebView *)webView shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)navigationType
```

This is triggered whenever a new URL request is about to load. From javascript, you could trigger a new request URL on the onfocus event of the  tag, with a custom schema like:

```
window.location = "webViewCallback://somefunction";
```

Here's a script to put your custom event inside any html page to load.

You'll have to get the whole HTML before loading it to the UIWebView like this:

```
NSString *html = [NSString stringWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"your URL"] encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:nil];
```

Then insert the following inside the HTML text in a appropriate place:

```
<script>
    var inputs = document.getElementsByTagName('input');

    for(int i = 0; i < inputs.length; i++)
    {
        if(inputs[i].type = "text")
        {
             inputs[i].onfocus += "javascript:triggerCallback()";
        }
    }

 function triggerCallback()
 {
      window.location = "webViewCallback://somefunction";
 }
</script>
```

Then, on the callback you should do something like this:

```
-(BOOL) webView:(UIWebView *)inWeb shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)inRequest navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)inType {
    if ( [[inRequest URL] scheme] == @"webViewCallback" ) {

        //Change the views position 

        return NO;
    }

    return YES;
}
```

That's it. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

Wow, I had the same problem few days ago, it was really annoying. I figured out that `window.yPageOffset` is changing, but as far as I know there aren't any events to bind when it changes. But maybe it will help you somehow. ;-)

Comment: yeah, and there's no possibility to get uiscrollview events after textfield focus - and that would be proper time to get window.yPageOffset. but thanks, anyway.

Answer (score 0):

I think you overwrote `scrollViewDidScroll` wrong.
You need to implement custom class for `UIWevView` and overwrite `scrollViewDidScroll`:

```
 - (void) scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView{
        [super scrollViewDidScroll:scrollView];
        [((id<UIScrollViewDelegate>)self.delegate) scrollViewDidScroll:scrollView];
    }
```