# iphone weview and scrolling ios 7.1

Tags: iphone, uiwebview

I have problem in ios7.1 the webview scroll up when focus on textBox/textarea. when keyboard up my header and I click on any button than show. Also in ios 7.0 for focus input field tap two times. [click here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7229882/uiwebviews-scrolling-after-textfield-focus). I use it but don't work.